# How to get the background-size:cover; size and percent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I would like to write a `jQuery` plugin to animate a `background-size` property from `cover` to `100%` and vice versa but I don't know how to get the `cover` to percent values, is it possible to get the resized width and height of a sized background image?

I know I can get `$('#selector').css('backgroundSize')` but I get `cover` and I would like to convert it in the current width and height of the background image, how can I do that?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think this is possible...Nothing in the [MDN spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-size) or [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size) suggests any correlation between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can get the dimensions of the image then you can check them against the dimensions of the container in which the image is the `background-image`. You can use these two pieces of information to turn `cover` into a percentage.

To get the dimensions of the image, create an `img` element to test:

```
$('<img />').bind('load', function () {
    //the image has loaded, you can now get it's height/width
}).addClass('offScreen').attr('src', '...');
```

The `offScreen` class is used to move the element off the screen while it loads so the user can't see it happening:

```
.offScreen {
    position : absolute;
    left     : -9999px;
}
```

Comment: It was so obvious that I haven't thought it!

Comment: I added an example of how to get the dimensions of an image without the user ever knowing.